# Calling sibling function and scope

Tags: reactjs

I want to know if I can call function1 from function2 or if I need to pass it down as props? I'm a bit confused because I am already passing props down via App.

```
function App(props) {
  function function1 {}
  function function2 {
    function1();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can call. These functions are not components. You are confusing functional components with methods(functions defined in components).In your case App is the functional component or in short just a component and function1 & function2 are methods inside the App component. You have access to other methods that are defined in the same component as the said method.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Good distinction.